# locating specific model from organizational economics

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request, mechanism-design, principal-agent, incentives

I am trying to find one specific model from organizational economics that I encountered in one of my past  classes, but I cant remember the name of the model and google scholar search based on some of the information below was not helpful, and I can't find my notes from that class either.

- The model was model of principal agent relationship where principal cannot observe agents ability.
- I recall that the feature of the model was that there was large pool of agents.
- The model was about setting up some incentive structure to exert agent put optimal level of effort.
- The outcome is supposed to be some mechanism that looks like sport competition, where you have one big prize for the 'winner(s)', but everyone else gets nothing.

I am also looking not just for the model name but also some reference that has some rigorous treatment of the model.

Comment: There is a large literature on "contests" which combines the ingredients above. Sometimes those are Tullock contests, sometimes contests similar to an all-pay auction.

Comment: @Bayesian thanks for pointers I will check it out, those terms sound vaguely familiar so I think that might be it, I will check it later, maybe consider posting it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a contest. There is a large economic literature on contests. Have a look at [this survey by Corchón and Serena](https://www.elgaronline.com/view/edcoll/9781788112772/9781788112772.00013.xml). Often these papers use a Tullock contest success function or model the contest as an all-pay auction, see, e.g., [papers by Ron Siegel](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.3982/ECTA7537).
There are papers that analyze given contests (research contests, lobbying, etc) and papers that look at contest design. I believe you are looking for the latter, i.e., some paper in which the contest arises as an optimal allocation mechanism maximizing the effort input of participants.